# Notepad++ fold all tags by default?

Tags: xml, notepad++, folding

I have a huge XML code that I keep adding to. It has about 13.465 lines of code, and a LOT of tags. To keep everything organised (Because, the code is almost unreadable), I decided I could just fold all my tags and comment as to what they are.

Is there any way to achieve this every time I open Notepad++ without having to use the "Fold all" option?? I'm using notepad++ windows XP, and XML.

Comment: Programming tool questions are on topic.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. Fits both criteria, please re-open.

Answer (score 76):

There is a way to [define a user-defined language](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/User_Defined_Languages) for you to tell Notepad++ to fold tabs by default.

This is an unnecessary procedure however, since you can ***very quickly*** fold tabs without having to specially create a user-defined language each time you have a large, clunky xml file.

Use the shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>...... <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to fold your `xml` tags in a sequence, depending on the depth you want to fold to. To expand only a particular level once again, just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click the `+` sign next to the tag you want to expand. This is the best way to view large blocks of *any* code in Notepad++, and avoids having to spend a lot of time configuring a special style for each language. Once your tabs are folded to the desired depth, you can insert comments where required. Few steps, easy results.

Comment: Actually it's not so fast, every time I try the shortcut it takes about 5 minutes

Comment: @ThePlan This worked in no time for me on a 5,000 line xml file, and my system is very fast, so I guess the implementation is CPU intensive. The Lexers for the xml language in `stylers.model.xml` don't have folding options defined, so to open an xml file with code folding, you need to [write your own Scintilla Lexer](http://www.scintilla.org/Lexer.txt). In my experience Notepad++ is never for large bulky files, so if you really want to use it in this case, you can look into this.

Comment: Yeah I work with a small team of developers and we use XML as a database, we have about 12.000 to 24.000 lines of code, and every 9 lines I have a fold, so that's why it takes so much. I will consider looking into another program to open XML files.

Comment: To complete @prrao's answer, ALT+SHIFT+0 will Expand All.

Comment: ALT + 0 will collapse all, ALT + Shift + 3 will Expand level three, or any level you type in.

Comment: thanks @AVIDeveloper and Des!